# Netstat Send-Q High

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, netstat

Am using Ubuntu Server 10.10 and when i do netstat -tuna i get the many connections with Send-Q very high, 23K, 50K, 100K. This users report that they have latency problems when connecting to the server. How can i enhance this or what tips can i learn to solve the Send-Q high results and lower latency for users. Server gets around 300 connections at the same time with each one using about 10K each. Server is 64Bit with 8 CPUs + 16GB RAM and a 100Mbit connection.